# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token "<"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app, amazon-eks, workbox

it's a weird issue I've got after I deployed my PWA application to prod (EKS). Some users and one of my brothers reported that they caught an issue which caused a white screen of death after refreshing and they had to refresh the page to use the application again. On my device, everything works just fine. I asked my brother about the error on the network tab in chrome's dev tools and these error lines showed up.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token "<" 2.9345ebBe.chunk.js:1
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token "<" main.fa04b6.chunk.js:1
```

Any idea? I asked my brother about his chrome version, his device, his setup, the steps to reproduce but no luck. I read some topics on stackoverflow too. They said that maybe it's all about cache problem. The system tries to read a js file but it actually an HTML file the "<" token is the "<" from <!doctype html>. I asked my brother to clear all the caches but he still got the problem. I have no idea what's going on.

**Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "my.pwa",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.9.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.8.1",
    "@mui/material": "^5.6.4",
    "@mui/styled-engine-sc": "^5.6.1",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.8.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.2",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "date-fns": "^2.28.0",
    "dexie": "^3.0.2",
    "env-cmd": "^10.1.0",
    "firebase": "^7.24.0",
    "framer-motion": "^6.5.0",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "moment": "^2.29.3",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.2.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-easy-crop": "^4.1.4",
    "react-infinite-scroll-component": "^6.1.0",
    "react-loading-skeleton": "^3.1.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.8",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "^2.1.3",
    "react-switch": "^7.0.0",
    "react-textarea-autosize": "^8.3.4",
    "redux": "^4.1.2",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "swiper": "^8.2.4",
    "uuid": "^7.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4",
    "wowjs": "^1.1.3"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:3006",
  "secure": false,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "build:development": "env-cmd -f .env.development react-scripts build",
    "build:production": "env-cmd -f .env.production react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {}
}
```

Comment: The < could be the start of a 404 page, page not found.

Comment: exactly brother

Comment: UPDATE: I just updated the react-scripts version from 2.1.3 to 3.4.0 let's see if we still see it

Comment: We can't debug your app from here. You're going to have to hunt down the line of code that is throwing the error and figure out where it maps to in the source.

Comment: properly, I found out that main.js fallbacked to index.html <noscript> instead "<" is the first character of the doctype tag

Comment: Hey guys, quick update, updating the version of react-scripts resolved the problem. Thanks.

Comment: I have react scripts 5.0.1 and this issue is driving me crazy. Sometimes it pops up, sometimes it works fine. I can trace it as as soon as it appears it decides to work on the next refresh. Clearing cache seems to sort it, and I think it maybe happen with a JWT expires and then refreshed. But its really difficult to track it down.