# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at main.js:1:1)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, create-react-app

[Unexpected token '<'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73325622/uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token)

Getting exactly this same issue, it appears sometimes and then keeps appearing and sometimes everything works smooth, same as the last comment mentioned under above issue, I'm using react-scripts 5.0.0 and yet getting the issue

I tried this https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2882#issuecomment-280906981
but it did not help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.